# Websync 4.0 PublisherNotAllowed

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, websync

I'm having a weird problem with websync 4.0: it works fine on my local machine, but when I deploy to a test server I get this error

```
System.Exception: Publication failed. result : {"channel":"\/n\/95e4d313-27eb-441b-966d-c8630f80ec9a","error":"606::Publisher access is disabled. Publisher access can be enabled by setting server[allowPublishers] to true in web.config.","ext":{"fm.meta":{"ticketID":""}}}
```

The thing is that I have 2 web applications developed on .net:

- one for the website
- one for the websync server

In both web.config files I've added

```
  <WebSync>
    <server providerType="FM.WebSync.Server.Providers.Sticky.InProcProvider" httpDirectPublish="true"/>
  </WebSync>
```

On localhost (where it works just fine) both IIS applications point to localhost.

From the website project I make a call via javascript to subscribe to a channel, and it works fine on both my machine and the test machine.

But when I try to send a message (and invite both parties to join a private channel) it only works on my local machine (this message sending is done via a http post to a method from the web site server which makes a publish to the websync server thus resulting in that error.)

Any ideas?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. After further investigation it turns out that Websync wasn't reading the web.config file (for some unknown reason).
I've managed to fix this by adding the following line in code:

```
Config.Current.Server.AllowPublishers = true;
```

Where ***Config*** is actually ***fm.websync.server.config***

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your websync is "not reading the web.config" is because you are using deprecated settings. The `httpDirectPublish` setting was for WebSync 3. For WebSync 4 this has been renamed to `allowPublishers`.

The documentation for WebSync 4 configuration is here: [WebSync 4 Configuration Docs](http://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/#class=websync-configuration)

Your web.config snippet above should look like this for WebSync 4:

```
<WebSync>
    <server allowPublishers="true" providerType="FM.WebSync.Server.InProcProvider" />
</WebSync>
```

NOTE: The `FM.WebSync.Server.InProcProvider` is the default, so you could technically omit that configuration.